# Newbie Question:Have to type localhost/controller/index in browser to get index method to display in Rails. Why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am new to Rails and I am reading Sitepoint's Simply Rails 2 but I am using Rails 3.0.0. In the book we had just set up our first controller (StoriesController) and fired up the server and typed in `http://localhost:3000/stories` and it should have displayed the `index.html.erb` file but instead when I type in that url I get "Routing Error: No route matches "/stories" but when I type in `http://localhost:3000/stories/index` it works properly. Can somebody explain to me why rails is not loading the index.html.erb file implicitly when I go to localhost/stories?

Comment: I have found that by adding `match ':controller(/:action(/:id(.:format)))'` to my routes.rb file, it fixes the problem, but does anyone know why we have to do this in Rails 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you created your routes (in `config\routes.rb`). Unfortunately, if you scaffold a controller, rails now generates a route like this:

```
get 'posts#index'
```

If it is a restful-controller, you better write

```
resources :posts
```

Or if it is a special controller (with only an index action) you could write

```
match '/posts' => 'posts#index'
```

To provide the fallback `match ':controller(/action(/:id(.:format)))` is generally avoided. Because it opens up all your controller-methods. The preferred way is that you declare explicitly how to access your site.